# How do I update a value not only in all documents but also in array of documents that a document can have?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of topics with data that looks like this:

```
{
  topicId:"LSCv0mnb" ,
  createdBy:"Sam",
  posts:[
   {
    postId: "nNP8UDxL",
    createdBy: "Sam"
   }, 
   {
    postId: "aJ8UxLa",
    createdBy: "Bob"
   }
 ]
}

{
  topicId:"hlsTOgAX" ,
  createdBy:"Victoria",
  posts:[
   {
    postId: "E3cJa0Nm",
    createdBy: "Sam"
   }, 
   {
    postId: "Rt0xQnAy",
    createdBy: "Jessica"
   }
 ]
}
```

What I need is to be able to find all `createdBy` where name is  `Sam` in all documents and in the array of `posts` and replace it with `[deleted]` for example:

```
{
  topicId:"LSCv0mnb" ,
  createdBy:"[deleted]",
  posts:[
   {
    postId: "nNP8UDxL",
    createdBy: "[deleted]"
   }, 
   {
    postId: "aJ8UxLa",
    createdBy: "Bob"
   }
 ]
}
```

I'm kind of lost how to do it correctly. Should I be using aggregations for it or what would be the way to do it ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$match` `createdBy` condition
- `$map` to iterate loop of `posts` array, check condition if `createdBy` is "Sam" then replace string otherwise nothiing

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { createdBy: "Sam" } },
  {
    $addFields: {
      createdBy: "[deleted]",
      posts: {
        $map: {
          input: "$posts",
          in: {
            postId: "$$this.postId",
            createdBy: {
              $cond: [
                { $eq: ["$$this.createdBy", "Sam"] },
                "[deleted]",
                "$$this.createdBy"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WaMC7ibqCY2)